# right sidebar is not where it has to be, moves to the bottom

Tags: html, css, wordpress, alignment, sidebar

I search the whole questions but I cannot find the solution, so here is my problem.

I have a forum webpage using forumengine theme by wordpress. In the main page and the category page everything is in order, sidebar appears where it has to be but when I click and enter the tread, the sidebar on the left moves to the bottom of the page. I cannot find the solution.

Can you tell me where is the problem?

You can see the problem I've mentioned at http://forum.banaisbul.com/Baslik/herkese-merhaba/

Answer (score 0):

Your html structure is messed up, particularly for using bootstrap.

**Solution 1(Ideal)**

The div containing the following class `col-md-3 marginTop18 thread-discuss-right hidden-sm hidden-xs` needs to be put under the `<div class="row">` that you have given so that grid will work.

**Solution 2**

The `col-md-9` margin that you have given should be removed and add to the immediate parent div.

Answer (score 0):

Add to the row element in your "container main center" the class "col-md-9".

```
<div class="row col-md-9">
```